# How to integrate Appium with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, specflow

I am unable to find a single post where i can automate mobile testing with appium in C#.

I have written my Website automation code in the specflow. Can I also Reuse it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Appium provides the [dotnet-appium-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-dotnet-driver) which is your API to interface with Appium. You can use that to write your app automation.

You did not provide any example here nor code, so I cannot really act on something to show you. I will just write down some C# code to let you understand how a simple test in C# can be written:

```
namespace AppiumTests
{
  using System;
  // .NET unit test namespaces needed here as well, just not mentioning them
  using OpenQA.Selenium; /* Appium is based on Selenium, we need to include it */
  using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium; /* This is Appium */

  [TestClass]
  public class TestSuite
  {
    private AppiumDriver driver;

    private static Uri testServerAddress = new Uri("http:127.0.01:4723/wd/hub"); // If Appium is running locally
    private static TimeSpan INIT_TIMEOUT_SEC = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180); /* Change this to a more reasonable value */
    private static TimeSpan IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT_SEC = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); /* Change this to a more reasonable value */

    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeAll()
    {
      DesiredCapabilities testCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

      testCapabilities.App = "<your-app-file>";
      testCapabilities.AutoWebView = true;
      testCapabilities.AutomationName = "";
      testCapabilities.BrowserName = String.Empty; // Leave empty otherwise you test on browsers
      testCapabilities.DeviceName = "Needed if testing on IOS on a specific device. This will be the UDID";
      testCapabilities.FwkVersion = "1.0"; // Not really needed
      testCapabilities.Platform = TestCapabilities.DevicePlatform.Android; // Or IOS
      testCapabilities.PlatformVersion = String.Empty; // Not really needed

      driver = new AppiumDriver(testServerAddress, capabilities, INIT_TIMEOUT_SEC);
      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT_SEC);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void AfterAll()
    {
      driver.Quit(); // Always quit, if you don't, next test session will fail
    }

    /// 
    /// Just a simple test to heck out Appium environment.
    /// 
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckTestEnvironment()
    {
      var context = driver.GetContext();
      Assert.IsNotNull(context);
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more in [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/antino/archive/2014/09/22/how-to-set-up-a-basic-working-appium-test-environment.aspx) I wrote.

Comment: Hey Andry , I am getting an error at driver = new AppiumDriver.....it says cannot create an instance of an abstract class or interface 'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver'  :(

Comment: Probably because I had you include too many things... just include the namespace in the edited answer. I am assuming you have the Appium dotnet driver dll linked  in your project.

Comment: Sorry , it still gives the same error :( , Also i replaced it with AndroidDriver();  it gives me error that : 
Result Message: 
System.InvalidOperationException : A new session could not be created. (Original error: No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set androidPackage to launch pre-existing app on device)

Comment: It is not the same error :) Now you can get to access Appium, of course you must specify an app file. What app do you want to test? You should write more info in your question. So here is what I need:
1) Do you need to automate an app already installed on your Android device? Or do you have an APK you want to install while testing?
2) In case you want to launch an existing app, I need to know the AppPackage and the AppActivity.
3) In case you want to instalkl it and have an APK file, move it on the PC where Appium is running and write down that path

Comment: Hey Andry ,things are sorted. I want to use a my website on the chrome and firefox in my device. i dont have an application but a website to be automated in the mobile chrome and firefox.  issue i am facing now is unable to open website in firefox and in chrome i get some session issue that session redirect from chrome ..

Comment: see my answer.  Thanks Andry , you rock!!

Comment: Andry , can i run the same code in ipad with appium in WINDOWS ?

Comment: Appium can be installed on Win and Mac, but it supports automation of apps only for iOS and Android. So if you want to automate Windows Phone or Surface, you cannot; but if you just want to run Appium on WIndowsn then you can!

Comment: my website runs ok for android. now same i want to run in ipad with safari. how can i do that ? some say i need xcode.  i just asked another queastion , its link goes here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676599/getting-error-xargs-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-whil

Comment: I'm not OP but am getting this error: `The type or namespace name 'DesiredCapabilities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I found the solution. It turns out the class is named `AppiumOptions` in C#.

Answer (score 8):

**Finally reached to the solution run a test in C#. Many Thanks to Andry.**

**This solution runs the website in the chrome browser of your phone connected to the computer :**

**Steps and short program to setup and run a C# program on an android device using Appium:**

```
namespace poc
{
    using NUnit.Framework;    
    using System;
    using OpenQA.Selenium; 
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Interfaces;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.MultiTouch;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;

    [TestFixture()]
    public class TestAppium
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
            capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "chrome");
            capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Motorola Moto g");
            capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
            capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");

             driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
        }  

        [Test()]
        public void OpenHofHomePage()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://YourWebsiteToTest.com");
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.Title.Equals("Your Website")," Sorry , the website didnt open!!");
        }

        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void End()
        {
            driver.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

1) Set up usual project in C# , install Appium , Selenium using NuGet package manager , Also install Nunit with the same process.

2) Download Android SDK

3) Envrionment variables : Add variable name "ANDROID_HOME" and in variable give path to sdk folder , In PATH (found in System variable) , append path to tools in sdk folder and append path to platform tools.

4) Connect your device (a.mobile device's drivers should be installed in the computer (my case moto g adb drivers installed) b. device should have developer mode option ON and debugger option checked and always awake option checked)

5) Now download Appium and open the Appium.exe.

6) Appium window -> In Android setting (first button) , check on "Use Browser" option and select "Browser" as an option.

7) Start the appium node server (play button at the top).

8) now run the test from the visual studio and you will see website opening in the browser of phone.

Answer (score 4):

To make this more comprehensive, I have written a blog post which explains all the steps clearly with images. Its a step by step tutorial to use appium with c# and MSTest
You can read it here. 
http://www.binaryclips.com/2016/03/test-automation-on-android-using-appium.html

Comment: Superb. a very self explanatory article.

Comment: @joinsaad. Your link does not work anymore. I got error "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist.". 
Is this yours? 
http://www.binaryclips.com/2016/03/test-automation-on-android-using-appium_27.html

Comment: Link is fixed, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have implemented Appium. I think it adds some depth to the discussion.

Appium is both a WebDriver that can interact with a device in your project as well as a Server that bridges your project to your physical device or emulator.

You have to run the Appium server as a listener and set up your Capabilities to connect to it. That will start the app and execute your test.

There is a lot more to it than this but here is a setup that you can try to get you on your way:

In a WebDriver Support Class use the [BeforeScenario] tag to execute this code before your test. This has a Sauce Labs implementation.

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    var name = Locale == "sauce" ? "AppiumSauceDriver" : "AppiumDriver";
    InitializeServiceLocator();
    if (WebDriver == null)
    {
        InitializeWebDriver(name);
    }

    ObjectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(WebDriver);

    if (WebDriver != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Driver Already Exists");
    }
}
```

Then you need to populate the InitializeServiceLocator() method. There is a Device Selector Method here that doesn't do anything other than set the name. You can just hard code it to your capabilities instead.

```
private static void InitializeServiceLocator()
{
    if (ServiceLocator == null)
    {
        var ip = "";
        var deviceType = TestSetupHelper.DeviceSelector["iphone7"];
        var capabilities = TestSetupHelper.SetAppiumCababilities(deviceType, Locale);
        string server = MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumServer");
        var port = Convert.ToInt32(MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumPort"));
        if (Locale != "sauce")
        {
            ip = TestSetupHelper.GetComputerIpAddress(server, port, true);
        }

        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind<IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>>().ToConstructor(x => new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))).Named("AppiumDriver");
        kernel.Bind<IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>>().ToConstructor(x => new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))).Named("AppiumSauceDriver");

        ServiceLocator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
        Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => ServiceLocator);
    }
}
```

From here you need to set up your capabilities. The below method is how I have done it.

```
public static DesiredCapabilities SetAppiumCababilities(string deviceType, string locale, bool realDevice = false, string udid = "FAKEUDIDFOREXAMPLE")
{
    string appiumAppFilePath = MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumAppFilePath");

    //Universal Capabilities
    capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", deviceType);
    capabilities.SetCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
    capabilities.SetCapability("app", appiumAppFilePath);
    capabilities.SetCapability("xcodeOrgId", "GET_THIS_FROM_APP_DEV");
    capabilities.SetCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
    capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
    capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", 80);

    if (locale == "sauce")//Sauce specific capabilities
    {
        capabilities.SetCapability("appiumVersion", "1.7.2");
        capabilities.SetCapability("name", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("appiumJobName"));
        capabilities.SetCapability("username", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("sauceId"));
        capabilities.SetCapability("accessKey", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("sauceKey"));
        capabilities.SetCapability("tunnel-identifier", MSTestContextSupport.GetRunParameter("sauceTunnel"));
        capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "11.2");
    }
    else//Local specific capabilities
    {
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "11.3");
    }

    if (realDevice)//Sauce real device testing will not need this. This is for Local Real Device testing only
    {
        capabilities.SetCapability("udid", udid);
    }

    return capabilities;
}
```

Anything referencing GetRunParameter is getting a value from a .runsettings file.

Example:

```
<TestRunParameters>
<Parameter name="appiumJobName" value="OBI App Automated Test"/>
</TestRunParameters>
```

You have to add all of the stuff to the .runsettings file you are using to run the project that you want to source from there. You can hardcode it if you don't want to go through the runsettings file but I prefer to do it that way. You can make things variable that way based on the runsettings file you have selected.

Then you have to define TestSetupHelper.GetComputerIpAddress(server, port, true); If you have a hard coded IP Address to the computer that is running your Appium server you can just hard code that. Otherwise you need a Helper class somewhere (In this example it is TestSetupHelper). This example initiates a Socket Connection to the server and returns all of the details. That way you don't have to worry about IP addresses changing. You just pass the host name and the port you have Appium configured to run on and you can get the connection information from that connection and make your actual connection to the Appium Server instance.

```
public static string GetComputerIpAddress(string computerName, int port, bool remote)
{
    var ip = "";
    using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
    {
        socket.Connect(computerName, port);
        //If remote it gets the connection destination IP, else it gets the connection initiator IP
        IPEndPoint endPoint = remote ? socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint : socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        ip = endPoint.Address.ToString();
    }

    return ip;
}
```

This isn't going to get you completely there but it will get you close to a working environment. Then you can start working on getting a test to actually run.

I hope this helps.