# Test website on android Mobile emulator using Selenium and c#

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-grid

I would like to run some selenium c# tests via an android emulator.

How can I do that?
Do I need another third Party ? EG Selendroid/

Can it run direct?

Is there any tutorial or links that takes you through the process?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test a android app you do need something like selendroid. have a look at [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/setup.html).

If you want to test a website on a mobile Android device you can go for an emulator like [Appium](http://appium.io) in combination with [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/grid/).

See getting started of [Appium getting started](http://appium.io/getting-started.html?lang=nl)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.I am trying to use Appium but I am struggling to set it up so that i can have something very noddy running on a windows 7 machine connecting to visual studio 2015 emulators.I have looked at the getting started but no luck there. Do you know where I can get a walkthrough how to set it up and run the first test?

Comment: Have you seen this question about c# and appium? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637796/how-to-integrate-appium-with-c i hope this will help you

Comment: my problem is not writing the test but all the steps required  and what to install so that i can see it running.

Comment: Quick question, did you enable developer mode? and are you running win 10
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

Comment: Is win10 mandatory can it work on win7 at work we only have win7.

Comment: As far as I'm aware Windows 10 is mandatory . I haven't got it to work on win 7. maybe you can get a trail licence to try it out.